# How can I request large amounts of persistent storage from HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, web-sql

On both mobile and desktop, using IndexedDB (on Firefo, Chrome, IE10) and WebSQL (on Safari), is there a way to ad-hoc request 50mb of persistent storage space from the browser?

Currently I am considering generating and pushing an array of size 1024*1024*50 to the persistent storage during initialization, but generating the array will take some time. I was wondering if there is a better, native way to do this.

Comment: Why do you need this kind of space taken up like that?

Comment: The app I am working on regularly fetches media and saves it locally. Each media file is between 100kb and 10MB+ in size.

Comment: So you want to save the space you need in advance? also these restrictions should tell you that you are using the wrong kind of storage. Same way you wouldn't these kind of things in a traditional DB

Comment: Yes, exactly. What kind of storage should we be using? We need to support IE9+, as well as Mobile+Desktop versions of Safari, Chrome, Firefox. Also, Android browser for some devices, and Kindle's Silk browser.

Comment: Save it on your servers, something like amazon S3